# Why onAttach() necessary for communication between activity and fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Why `onAttach()` method is necessary for communication between activity and fragment
for ex below code:-

```
public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {

Fragmentinterface interf;

public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Fragmentinterface) {
        interf = (Fragmentinterface) context;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException("exception message");
    }
}
```

Why `interf = (Fragmentinterface) context;` casting of activity to interface refrence is necessary?
Why it is not as simple that Mainactivity implements interface and calls interface method with method body and this method also called in fragment with interface refrence to communicate between activity and fragment?

As a newbie might be iam lacking some core java knowledge...please  explain

Answer (score 2):

> Why interf = (Fragmentinterface) context; casting of activity to
>   interface refrence is necessary?

Because we only want to access the method of particular interface, not all methods of `MainActivity`

> Why it is not as simple that Mainactivity implements interface and
>   calls interface method with method body

`interf` is `null`, first we need to initialise it and here we want to pass data to activity and often data is further used by other methods of activity though you can use lambdas, anonymous classes as parameter but it should be done inside the scope of activity, Scope defines the bounderies and one way to communicate is public methods.

Note: you can do the casting later in other lifecycle methods when context is ready to use though onAttach is the first place to use the `context`.